# Apache Beam/Dataflow: KVCoder corrupting Inputstream for decode

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, iostream, avro, apache-beam

I have custom objects: `CustomKey`, `CustomValue` which I provided coder via Avro: `CustomKeyCoder`, `CustomValueCoder`.

Since I need to group by KV[CustomKey, CustomValue], I registered `KVCoder.of(new CustomKeyCoder, new CustomValueCoder)`. Custom coders wraps in/out stream to data in/out stream and uses Avro Datum Writer/Reader.

Issue I am having is in the decode of the KVCoder, when we attempt to decode value part of `KV` I get `Forbidden IOException when reading from InputStream`. As noted, key part of decoding works properly, error is thrown when input stream is passed into decoding value. KVCoder reuses same input stream for both key and value I am guessing key decoding reads entire stream. Why would this be happening? Is usage of Avro a problem?

Here is some code to showcase above:

```java
  //Coder
  override def decode(inputStream: InputStream): CustomValue = {
    val dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(inputStream)
    val id = dataInputStream.readShort
    underlying.decode(dataInputStream)
  }

 //Underlying
  override def decode(inputStream: InputStream): CustomValue = {
    val decoder = DecoderFactory.get().binaryDecoder(inputStream, null)
    val record = datumReader.read(null, decoder)
    CustomValue.decode(record)
  }
```